# How can I use AWS DAX in my node.js app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I've a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/) app where I've used `mongodb` as persistent layer and `redis` as cache.

**However I want to move to [AWS DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) so that I can hold large dataset in cache and also I want to use dynamodb as mongodb replacement.**

[sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/) has a waterline adapter for [dynamodb](https://github.com/gadelkareem/sails-dynamodb) But I am not sure how I can use [AWS DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) on my app.

I've found one example with java in [aws dynamodb docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.modify-your-app.html) But not sure how can I use on my node.js app.

Thanks in adavance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAX has just released a Node.js client. Check the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.run-application-nodejs.html) for how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Today, DAX supports an SDK for Java, and does not yet have an SDK for Node.js

Comment: yeah, I got that. Right now I'm making a POC with node-java to test whether I can use that java library in node app.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the DAX, but for DynamoDB- if you want an ORM, 
so if the waterline adapter is good for you so use it, when I checked it a few months ago I got an impression that it's not well-maintained but it looks like lately it's active again so maybe this can be a good solution.

Anyway, you can also check Vogels: https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels/

Note there in Github issues #171 and #198

Dynogels:
https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

Comment: I've already mentioned about the dynamodb adapter in my question https://github.com/gadelkareem/sails-dynamodb and it's using vogels internally. what I am really looking for a solution for DAX (dynamodb part  was required to give some context). Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

#### (1st July 2017)

As an update, I've tried to use dax with node.js using node-java, I was able to create dynamodb tables but not able to use dax feature as I would have expected. There is some exception coming up using dax.

I've contacted with aws support and they said they are working on aws-javascript sdk to support dax but there is no speicific release date.

However, if anyone interested on how I've tried they may look at https://github.com/jsec516/node-dax/tree/with-try-dax There is some manual setup required on ec2 instance and also you've to compile the java files before you try to run it.

Let me know if you need any help to run.